# sql union syntax error for 2 sql statements

Tags: sql

I have an sql syntax in my php script that gives me an error. All I want is to get the result of 2 sql statemet.

```
$sql1 = " SELECT `name`, `surname`, `email`, `user_id` FROM users WHERE (surname LIKE '$name%' AND name LIKE '$surname%') OR (surname LIKE '$surname%' AND name LIKE '$name%') ";
```

and

```
$sql2 = " SELECT profile_id from profile WHERE `country`='uk'   ";
```

I want to get values from my database for both $sql1 and $sql2. I use UNION statement like this but it did not work. Any ideas how to fix it :

```
$sql = " (SELECT `name`, `surname`, `email`, `user_id` FROM users WHERE (surname LIKE '$name%' AND name LIKE '$surname%') OR (surname LIKE '$surname%' AND name LIKE '$name%')) UNION (SELECT profile_id from profile WHERE `country`='uk' )  ";
```

Comment: In order for `union` to work both queries must have the **SAME** set of columns. Are you sure that union is what you need? if you need to have results from both tables why not joining them

Answer (score 5):

A UNION query must have same output fields.

> The select queries that you combine in a union query must have the
>   same number of output fields, in the same order, and with the same or
>   compatible data types.